# Create a Matlab Live Script

Tags: macos, matlab

I recently found out about Live Scripts, which seems like a cool Matlab feature (similar to Playgrounds in Swift). However, following along with the documentation [here](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-live-scripts.html), I'm unable to create one. I don't see anything in the documentation to suggest that this is a plugin. The results of the three suggested options for creation are below (I'm on OS X, if that makes a difference):

1. On the Home tab, in the New drop-down menu, select Live Script.

**There's no option for Live Script:**

[image]

2. Highlight commands from the Command History, right-click, and select Create Live Script.

**There's no option for Live Script:**

[image]

3. Use the edit function. To ensure that a live script is created, specify a .mlx extension. For example: `edit penny.mlx`

**Matlab Editor triggers an error:**

[image]

Comment: [You need R2016a](http://www.mathworks.com/products/new_products/latest_features.html?s_tid=hp_spot_R2016a_0316)

Comment: Dang. Thanks! You're all over the place on this Matlab stuff; very helpful!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Live Scripts are a new feature in MATLAB R2016a. If your version is older than that, you won't be able to take advantage of Live Scripts.